# openpyxl: error handling when reading cell data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have an xlsm file which is prepared by human. Understandably, some cells were wrongly formatted. For example there's some columns which supposed to contains integer strings as ID, but some of the cells would be wrongly formatted as Datetime. When reading these cells, openpyxl would issue an warning and mark these cells as an error when it is unable to parse the integer to datetime format, e.g.:

> ...\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py:223: UserWarning: Cell G14935 is marked as a date but the serial value 1713074675 is outside the limits for dates. The cell will be treated as an error.
> warn(msg)

I googled a solution for this for hours, including searching for error handling methods when reading cells, setting datatypes for columns or cells(was using pandas to read the file, but I traced the error to openpyxl), but to no avail. What I needed is a way to override the saved cell's datatype, and try to load its values as different type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: Reading the file via pandas does not help: there are suggestions to use keywords dtype='string' when calling pd.read_excel, unfortunately it seems the problematic cells will be read according to the cells datatype first, then converted into the requested datatype.

Comment: Openpyxl's behaviour was decided after considerable discussions with people in similar situations. The warning is clear and it gives you all the information you need to make adjustments, either before you read the file in openpyxl or afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is anything else you can try with Pandas.

You should be able to fix using `Xlwings` simply by changing the number format. (Note doing this in Openpyxl will not work, see the Openpyxl option below this Xlwings option).

```
import xlwings as xw

xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

    ### Note you should be able to see the cell value using the formula field of 
    ### the cell irrespective of changing the number format. But you must change
    ### the number format to 'fix' the cell value
    print(ws['A1'].formula)  # Would print 1713074675 

    ### To fix; Set the number format to General or other appropriate format like 
    ###   0 for number format with no decimal places 
    ###   '#,##0' for number format with no decimal places & thousands separators
    ws['A1'].number_format = 'General'
    print(ws['A1'].value) 

    wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

############ Option with Openpyxl ############
As with the comment from Charlie Clark below; you can fix these fields with Openpyxl
As Charlie mentions the details are in the warning message so you can capture the warnings and update the fields from that.

An example of this is below;
This code captures the `UserWarning` that contain the error details, extracts the cell coordinate and value into a dictionary. Then opens the sheet updates the cell, changing the number format to number with no decimal places and then saves the workbook.

```
import warnings
import openpyxl as xl
import re


change_dict = {}  # Holds the coordinate and value for the error cells
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as captured_warnings:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    ### Open workbook and capture the warnings
    wb = xl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')

    ### Loop the captured warnings find those of type UserWarning
    for warn in captured_warnings:
        ### If Warning type is UserWarning
        if issubclass(warn.category, UserWarning):
            msg = str(warn.message)
            print(f"Message: {msg}")

            ### Extract the cell coordinate and value from the message
            ### Cell coordinate; 'word' after '^Cell'
            cell_coord = re.findall(r"(?<=^Cell)\b \w+\b", msg)[0].strip()
            ### Cell value; 'word' after 'serial value'
            cell_value = re.findall(r"serial value\.?([ \d.]+)", msg)[0].strip()
            ### Add the coord and value to the dictionary
            change_dict[cell_coord] = cell_value

### Create worksheet object
ws = wb['Sheet1']

### Update the cell value and set its format to 'number'
for c_coord, c_value in change_dict.items():
    ws[c_coord].value = int(c_value)
    ws[c_coord].number_format = '0'

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: Actually, if catch and collect the warnings you can do this in openpyxl. It's not ideal but should be doable. A nice challenge for you! ;-)

Comment: The openpyxl's script worked for me. And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72373268/21896093) that suggests loading the data in using `xlwings`, then you can change cell formatting to `'General'` and save the modified table. The modified table ought to load without error when you read it in via `pandas`.